# Django - schema_editor in migration error - Apply conditional migrations

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I am trying to figure out how to use schema_migration inside Django Migrations.

The main reason, is to apply a conditional migration, check if the **field minimal_variant_price_amounte** exists, if no, apply the migration.

```py
from django.db import migrations
from django.core.exceptions import FieldDoesNotExist


def populate_product_minimal_variant_amount_field_check(apps, schema_editor):
    Product = apps.get_model("product", "Product")
    try:
        Product._meta.get_field('minimal_variant_price_amounte')
    except FieldDoesNotExist:
        print(schema_editor)
        schema_editor.alter_field(
            Product, 'minimal_variant_price', 'minimal_variant_price_amount')
        print(' field change: minimal_variant_price => minimal_variant_price_amount')


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('product', '0106_django_prices_2'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(
            populate_product_minimal_variant_amount_field_check,
            reverse_code=migrations.RunPython.noop,
        )
    ]
```

I got the error:

**Projetos/Django/indevos-ecommerce/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 505, in alter_field
    old_db_params = old_field.db_parameters(connection=self.connection)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'db_parameters'**

Comment: What error/problem do you get?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I add the error in the description, thanks!